# jQuery Multiple selection

Tags: jquery, multi-select

I am trying to select more than one category in this "Filterable jQuery Portfolio." Currently the widget is functional and correctly sorts when one item is selected. I am trying to select multiple categories which then filter items.

Here is an example image

[jQuery image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXimZ.jpg)

Here is the jQuery code, I am unsure whether to use "MultiSelect" and where to place it.

```
    jQuery('document').ready(function() {
// PORTFOLIO SORTING
jQuery('div.nimble-portfolio-filter ul li a').click(function() {
    jQuery(this).css('outline','none');
    jQuery('div.nimble-portfolio-filter ul .current').removeClass('current');
    jQuery(this).parent().addClass('current');
    var filterVal = jQuery(this).attr('rel');
    if(filterVal == 'all') {
        jQuery('div.nimble-portfolio ul li.hidden').fadeIn('normal').removeClass('hidden');
    } else {
        jQuery('div.nimble-portfolio ul li').each(function() {
            if(!jQuery(this).hasClass(filterVal)) {
                jQuery(this).fadeOut('normal').addClass('hidden');

            } else {
                jQuery(this).fadeIn('normal').removeClass('hidden');
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is a link of the [demo](http://www.nimble3.com/portfolio/)

Comment: Is "Filterable jQuery Portfolio" the name of a widget? Can you add a link to the web site to your question?

Comment: Thanks for the response, yes  "Filterable jQuery Portfolio" the name of a widget. It is a WordPress widget which I'm currently using in MAMP (Localhost) so I can't share a demo. Let me try to narrow down the specific function.

Comment: Here is a working demo of the same plugin I am using http://www.nimble3.com/portfolio/